# How can I find questions favorited by at least $n$ users?

Tags: support, search, bookmarks

**Motivation**:
Being on math.SE for a month, I noticed that almost every non-trivial question is favorited by a user.  Got a bit tired searching for a problem I can think of, among questions that are likely homework or a person got stuck or things on which I don't have a clue about (e.g. "Given a locally compact Hausdorf space, ...").

So the **question** is:

> How can I view questions, favorited at least by $1$ person (hmm, or maybe $5$)?

I've already seen `infavorites:id` in search, but there seems to be no option 
`infavorites:*` available. It turns out that I can use `favorite_count>0` but I do not know how to manage with it.

Comment: Favorites might not always indicate quality; I often favorite to track a question for whatever reason (e.g. to see if it gets edited/closed/deleted/undeleted/reopened).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since  there is no search parameter to access the favorite count, one has to use [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) for this purpose.

Here is the query [Questions favorited at least N times](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/317923/questions-favorited-at-least-n-times?mincount=1) which shows the title, number of answers, whether there is an accepted answer, etc.

The main drawback of using Data Explorer is that the data it has can be up to a week old; it is refreshed every weekend.

---

But I am skeptical that you will find the raw number of favorites to be of much help. Here is an effective method to find nontrivial unanswered questions of interest to you:

1. Select some [favorite tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics).
2. [Bookmark this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20answers%3a0); it's the *second* page of search results for `intags:mine answers:0`, sorted by newest.